# Blank output command substitution - FTP

Tags: bash, ftp, output

When trying to record all output into a variable of a FTP session, the variable is blank. I've tried the following variations all with the same result:

```
OUT=$(ftp -in $FTP_HOST << END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $FTP_USER
  quote PASS $FTP_PASS
  binary
  cd /home/ftp/files
  get test.txt
  quit
END_SCRIPT
)

echo $OUT
```

Variation #2:

```
OUT=$(ftp -in $FTP_HOST 2>&1 << END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $FTP_USER
  quote PASS $FTP_PASS
  binary
  cd /home/ftp/files
  get test.txt
  quit
END_SCRIPT
)

echo $OUT
```

Is there some other place output would be written to?

Comment: The `$(...)` syntax will only capture things on `stdout`.  Anything printed to `stderr` or written to the terminal would not be captured.  If you're trying to record the whole session have you considered using the `script` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

piping `| tee` worked for my use case